# shift out time taking as next date in time in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am a admin of a bio-metric device, there are 3 shifts are going in my office.

```
                    In time                                    Out time                           Date

Shift1           6AM                                       2PM                                   5th April
Shift2           2PM                                       10PM                                 5th April
Shift3           10PM      5th April                6AM                                   6th April
```

but the 3rd shift time intime 10PM is taking as

```
 In time          Out Time
day1   out time      10PM
day2 in time 6AM
```

How can I make it for same date 10PM as intime and 6AM as out time in excel?

And also I want to generate it automatically.
I want the Out Time must shown as the same date.

```
Date             Intime           Outtime

5.4.17          6AM               2PM
5.4.17          2PM               10PM
5.4.17         10PM              6AM
```

And I want to automate the report while generating from web.

Answer (score 0):

=Now() will generate a number (double type) like 42832.8008217593 where the date is shown on the left of the period and the time on the right. 10 PM (22:00:00) will be expressed as 0.9166666667. Add 8 hours to this number (1/24*8) and the result is 1.25 which means, in plain language, "next day 6 AM".

To solve your problem you can use a condition, like, If the end time is on the next day, deduct one day from the result date. This would mean 1.25 - 1 = 0.25 = 6:00AM on the day which is one day earlier than it actually is. Whether your end time is a proper date/time, like 42833.25 or a relative time like 1.25 depends upon how you enter your data.

You can extract the time from the date/time value by calculating (Date/Time - Int(Date/Time), like 1.25 - Int(1.25) = 1.25 -1 = 0.25